# Have some trouble with python format function

Tags: python, python-3.x

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZZks.jpg)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvQJ4.jpg)

```
var1 = 'ketchup'
regularprice = 12.80
discount_percentage = 0.27
finalprice = regularprice*(1-discount_percentage)

print('${:.2f} is the sale price of ketchup.'. format(finalprice))

print('${:.2f}is the sale price of' + ' ' + var1 + '.'. format(finalprice))
```

As shown above, I found that the second 'print' which added a variable could not display correctly. The format function didn't work.

Could anybody give me some hints? : )

Comment: Please post the code, not images...

Comment: Sorry about that. It's my first time to ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is operator precedence; `.` binds more tightly than `+`. To use `.format()` on a string made from several pieces, you would have to use brackets.

In this case, though, it's much better to use `.format` to put in both values:

```
print('${:.2f} is the sale price of {:s}.'.format(finalprice, var1))
```

Or, since the `s` format is the default:

```
print('${:.2f} is the sale price of {}.'.format(finalprice, var1))
```

If you're using a sufficiently recent version of Python, you can also use f-strings:

```
print(f'${finalprice:.2f} is the sale price of {var1}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is:

```
print('${:.2f} is the sale price of ' + var1 + ('.'.format(finalprice)))
```

What you need is:

```
print(('${:.2f} is the sale price of ' + var1 + '.').format(finalprice))
```

Please note the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
print('${:.2f} is the sale price of'.format(finalPrice) + varl + '.')
```

With your code, Python will understand that you are using `format` function for the third string element `'.'` which has nothing to format